# embedding flash using AC_FL_RunContent slighlty crops flash in IE8 only

Tags: actionscript-3, internet-explorer-8, embed

Has anyone encountered a bug when using AC_FL_RunConten to embed flash?
In IE8 it seems that the flash is slightly cropped on all 4 sides.

Is there a known workaround?

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me, here is my standard code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

html, body  { height:100%; }
            body { margin:0; padding:0; overflow:auto; text-align:center; 
                   background-color: #ffffff; }
            object:focus { outline:none; }
            #flashContent { display:none; }

```
    <!-- BEGIN Browser History required section -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="history/history.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="history/history.js"></script>
    <!-- END Browser History required section -->  

    <script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        <!-- For version detection, set to min. required Flash Player version, or 0 (or 0.0.0), for no version detection. --> 
        var swfVersionStr = "10.0.0";
        <!-- To use express install, set to playerProductInstall.swf, otherwise the empty string. -->
        var xiSwfUrlStr = "playerProductInstall.swf";
        var flashvars = {};
        var params = {};
        params.quality = "high";
        params.bgcolor = "#ffffff";
        params.allowscriptaccess = "sameDomain";
        params.allowfullscreen = "true";
        var attributes = {};
        attributes.id = "TimelineDemo";
        attributes.name = "TimelineDemo";
        attributes.align = "middle";
        swfobject.embedSWF(
            "TimelineDemo.swf", "flashContent", 
            "100%", "100%", 
            swfVersionStr, xiSwfUrlStr, 
            flashvars, params, attributes);
        <!-- JavaScript enabled so display the flashContent div in case it is not replaced with a swf object. -->
        swfobject.createCSS("#flashContent", "display:block;text-align:left;");
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- SWFObject's dynamic embed method replaces this alternative HTML content with Flash content when enough 
         JavaScript and Flash plug-in support is available. The div is initially hidden so that it doesn't show
         when JavaScript is disabled.
    -->
    <div id="flashContent">
        <p>
            To view this page ensure that Adobe Flash Player version 
            10.0.0 or greater is installed. 
        </p>
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            var pageHost = ((document.location.protocol == "https:") ? "https://" : "http://"); 
            document.write("<a href='http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer'><img src='" 
                            + pageHost + "www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif' alt='Get Adobe Flash player' /></a>" ); 
        </script> 
    </div>

    <noscript>
        <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="100%" height="100%" id="TimelineDemo">
            <param name="movie" value="TimelineDemo.swf" />
            <param name="quality" value="high" />
            <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
            <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
            <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
            <!--[if !IE]>-->
            <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="TimelineDemo.swf" width="100%" height="100%">
                <param name="quality" value="high" />
                <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
                <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
                <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
            <!--<![endif]-->
            <!--[if gte IE 6]>-->
                <p> 
                    Either scripts and active content are not permitted to run or Adobe Flash Player version
                    10.0.0 or greater is not installed.
                </p>
            <!--<![endif]-->
                <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
                    <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash Player" />
                </a>
            <!--[if !IE]>-->
            </object>
            <!--<![endif]-->
        </object>
    </noscript>
```

Show me yours please, including screenshot and IE full version with build.

Thank you
Eugene